# How do I ignore gitignore in magit?

Tags: git, emacs, magit

I have some file extensions ignored in my `.gitignore`.  I'd like to force-stage a particular one of them.

Given the `C-g` magit buffer, how can I get a view that ignores my `.gitignore` so that I can identify and force stage the single file I'd like to commit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few alternatives:

- Since Magit 2.13, if you add `magit-insert-ignored-files` to <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `magit-status-sections-hook` and refresh the status buffer, you'll see all the ignored files in a separate collapsible section, and can act on them from there.
- Delete `.gitignore` (maybe within Magit via <kbd>!</kbd><kbd>s</kbd>), refresh the status buffer if necessary, stage what you want to stage, and then tell Magit to revert the deleted `.gitignore`.
- Use <kbd>:</kbd> (or a terminal) to run the `git add` command manually, rather than using the Magit UI.